# Binding "this" when passing an object's member function

Tags: javascript, singleton, closures

I had a "class" defined and was making only one instance of it. The instance possessed a member function that would end up being passed around (it's a mouse handler, but that's not important). Since I would only ever make one instance of my "class", I decided to rewrite it as a singleton by using an object literal.

So I have

```
var mySingleton = {
    theObjects : [];
}

mySingleton.mouseHandler = (function() {
    var that = this;
    return function (e) {
        for (var indx = 0; indx < that.theObjects.length; indx++) {
            // do something to that.theObjects[indx];
        }
    }
}());

mySingleton.addObject = function(newObj) {
    this.theObjects.push(newObj);
}
```

However, when I try to use this code (after adding a few objects), I keep getting an that.theObjects is undefined error. It's referring to the line in the for loop.

Comment: the line `var mySingleton = { theObjects = []; }` should be `var mySingleton = { theObjects : [] }`. Not sure if this the problem though

Comment: You just wrote the same thing twice...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a typo in my stackoverflow question. It is indeed a colon in my code, so that's not the issue. I will edit my post accordingly tho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update for 2015** – Use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to specify the value of `this` within the function.  Then, instead of using `that`, you can use `this`.

```
mySingleton.mouseHandler = function (e) {
    for (var indx = 0; indx < this.theObjects.length; indx++) {
        // do something to this.theObjects[indx];
    }
}.bind(mySingleton);
```

This doesn't work if you want `mouseHandler` to have the context of the 'moused' element.  For that, use my original answer below.

If you need to support IE8 or (heaven forbid) earlier, you'll need to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).

---

Since you are calling the function that creates `mouseHandler` immediately, it is run in the context of `window`, not `mySingleton`.  So `that` refers to `window`.  Instead of calling it immediately, just change it to a method so that it runs in the context of `mySingleton`:

```
mySingleton.getMouseHandler = function() {
    var that = this;
    return function() { ... };
};
myElement.onclick = mySingleton.getMouseHandler();
```

Of course, since you are already using a singleton, you can just reference it directly.  In your click handler, instead of checking `that.theObjects`, check `mySingleton.theObjects`.  Or, in `mouseHandler` change `var that = this` to `var that = mySingleton`.

**Edit:** Or, pass the context to your anonymous function when you call it:

```
mySingleton.mouseHandler = (function() {
    var that = this;
    return function (e) {
        for (var indx = 0; indx < that.theObjects.length; indx++) {
            // do something to that.theObjects[indx];
        }
    }
}).call(mySingleton);
```

Comment: @highwind - Indeed.  Click handlers are function objects.  The alternative is to create your entire object in a closure.

Comment: Yes they are, but wouldn't it be more efficient to have only ONE function object for the handler, instead of having a factory that produces them?

Comment: @highwind - I thought up a simpler solution.  See my updated answer.

Comment: suppose mySingleton is not in the global namespace

Comment: Then how are you setting `mouseHandler`?  You must have a reference to it at that time, which is all you need:  `objReference.mouseHandler = (function(){...}).call(objReference)`

Comment: oh, actually, mySingleton doesn't need to be in the global namespace for your solution. My bad. Great answer!

As for "The alternative is to create your entire object in a closure", that's what I really wanted to do. Except it doesn't work as closures normally would. I don't simply want closure on a private variable. I want closure on a reference to "this", an object that has not yet been created. `mySingleton = (function() { var that = this; ... return { theObjects: [], mouseHandler: function(e) { ... }, ... } }( );`

Comment: @highwind - use the `new` keyword.  `var mySingleton = new (function(){ var that = this; ... })();`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few popular ways to do this.  First, super-simple solution is just reference mySingleton directly and bypass the confusion associated with `this`.  Instead of `that.theObjects` just do `mySingleton.theObjects` and move on with your life and things will work fine.

However, there is a common pattern to do this binding. Here's [how underscore.js does it](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind)

Check out the [annoted source to underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html), where you will find this

```
 _.bind = function(func, obj) {
    if (func.bind === nativeBind && nativeBind) return nativeBind.apply(func, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return function() {
      return func.apply(obj, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
```

Comment: (sorry, don't know how to put code blocks in comments...)
"mySingleton.theObjects" will work if mySingleton is in the global namespace. So it doesn't generalize to, say, "var mySingleton" declared within a function. How to get a generalized solution? 

As for "a common pattern to do this binding", I was under the impression that creating a closure and binding "that" to "this" was the common way of doing things (as per Crockford). Why doesn't doesn't my code work. I am pulling my hair out because I simply cannot understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: @highwind - Your code doesn't work because the anonymous function that creates `mouseHandler` is run in the Global context, so `that` ends up referring to `this`.  See my answer.

Comment: @gilly3 - That's weird. I thought I would have caught a stupid mistake like that. Oh, I see you made an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here so far are also correct.  Providing my viewpoint here in case it helps.

The key to understanding why the code doesn't behave as you expect requires understanding how `this` works in JavaScript.  The problem is that `this` depends on how the function is called.

First, if you call the function in the method style, `this` is what you'd expect:

```
mySingleton.mouseHandler(); // this === mySingleton
```

If you attach the function to something esle, that works too.

```
var anotherSingleton = {};
anotherSingleton.foo = mySingleton.mouseHandler;
anotherSingleton.foo(); // this === anotherSingleton
```

If you detach the function, `this` becomes the global scope object (`window`)

```
var foo = mySingleton.mouseHandler;
foo(); // this === window
```

And finally, you can force `this` to be something else using `call` or `apply`:

```
var randomThingy = {};
mySingleton.mouseHandler.call(randomThingy); // this === randomThingy
```

The takeaway is that `this` is determined at runtime based on the context of how the function was called.  Often, frameworks that allow you to make "classes" abstract these details from you by implicitly applying the bind pattern on your behalf.  This is why it used to work, and no longer does.

As others have mentioned, you can change your handler to reference the variable by its scoped name (`mySingleton`) or otherwise bind it as discussed.

Here's an article I wrote on the subject a few years ago that goes into more detail: http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=Understanding_JavaScript%27s_this_keyword

Hope this helps!