# Javascript objects and passing member functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, function, object, arguments

This is hard to explain, maybe it's better if I write some sample code:

```
function A()
{
    this.b = new B();

    this.a_value = 456;

    this.f = function(i)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.a_value; ++i)
            DoStuff(i);
    }

    this.b.C(this.f)
}
```

I'm trying to pass a function as an argument to B, but when C tries to reach a_value it's undefined. How do I fix it?

I hope I didn't oversimplify my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Now (or since 2015 apparently), you can also bind the function to the object instance as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739960/308237):

```
this.b.C(this.f.bind(this));
```

By way of an explanation:

```
var fn = myObject.myFunction.bind(myObject);

// The following two function calls are now equivalent
fn(123);
myObject.myFunction(123);
```

Comment: Excellent answer! The other answers resort to using a random named variable to store `this`, which works, but is not very maintainable in a big long-lived code-base

Answer (score 2):

You ca pass `this.f` to function `c`, but to call it properly, you need to also pass the value of `this` like this:

```
function A()
{
    this.b = new B();

    this.a_value = 456;

    this.f = function(i)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.a_value; ++i)
            DoStuff(i);
    }

    this.b.C(this.f, this)   // <== pass "this" here
}

And, then in `this.b.c`:

...b.c = function(fn, context) {
   fn.call(context);      // <== use .call() here to apply the right this value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` isn't bound to any fixed value in JavaScript. You can use a closure to fix this, and it's probably the best way in this case:

```
function A()
{
    var that = this;

    this.b = new B();

    this.a_value = 456;

    this.f = function(i)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < that.a_value; ++i)
            DoStuff(i);
    }

    this.b.C(this.f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way of achieving the same thing using an arrow function.  Since arrow functions do not bind `this` it will retain whatever value it had when the function was defined.

```
function A()
{
    this.b = new B();

    this.a_value = 456;

    this.f = i =>
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.a_value; ++i)
            DoStuff(i);
    }

    this.b.C(this.f)
}
```